# databricks sql watermark syntax

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

Need some help regarding watermark syntax with DLT sql pipeline setup.

Wanted to load combined data from 2 silver layer steaming table into a single table with watermarking so it can capture late updates  but having some syntax error.

### SQL query to get combined data

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE  target_table
AS 
SELECT 
*
FROM STREAM(LIVE.silver_table1)   a
LEFT JOIN STREAM (LIVE.silver_table2) b
      ON a.Id=b.Id
```

But when try to add watermark logic  then getting ParseException error

Syntax used for 1 of the table

```
FROM STREAM(LIVE.silver_table1)  WATERMARK LastUpdateDateTime DELAY OF INTERVAL 60 SECONDS
```

### Error

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'LastUpdateDateTime'(line 22, pos 54)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the placement of the WATERMARK logic in your SQL statement.

Usually, the syntax for using WATERMARK with a streaming source in SQL depends on the database system. But the general format is

```
FROM STREAM (stream_name) WATERMARK watermark_column_name <DELAY OF> <delay_interval>
```

Try this.

**Syntax:**

```
%sql
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE target_table
AS
SELECT *
FROM STREAM(LIVE.silver_table1)
WATERMARK LastUpdateDateTime DELAY OF INTERVAL 60 SECONDS a
LEFT JOIN STREAM (LIVE.silver_table2) b ON a.Id = b.Id;
```

[image]